# Нужно ли самому реализовывать алгоритмы?

Tags: алгоритм

Интересно узнать как в реальных проектах относятся к копированию чужого кода, можно ли брать код алгоритмов из свободного доступа, зная, как и что делает этот алгоритм?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы никогда не будете достаточно продуктивны если не будете использовать результаты чужого труда.

Comment: Имейте в виду, что использование чужого кода может быть ограничено его лицензией (а если лицензии вообще нет, то использовать код по умолчанию нельзя)

Comment: @andreymal, я думаю, что эта парадигма должна умереть. Правильный подход -- используй все, до чего можешь дотянуться

Comment: @avp идеологически я с вами согласен, но вот юридически копирасты будут не очень довольны

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не поверите - половина проектов состоит из чужого кода

Если алгоритм полностью подходит под решение Вашей задачи и Вы уверены что он написан хорошо в плане [сложности](https://habr.com/ru/post/188010/) и чистоты кода, то изобретать велосипед не стоит и можно использовать его.

Однако, как в комментариях выше написал Stanislav Volodarskiy, если делать это постоянно и бездумно, то опыта Вы получите гораздо меньше.

Comment: Ну вообще-то обычно подключают готовый модуль, а не копипастят код...

Comment: @Qwertiy, речь не о модулях, а об алгоритмах.

Comment: интересная интерпретация комментария Stanislav-а  ;-)